# Spatie Laravel Permissions - How To Get Users that have one Role or another Role

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I'm trying to figure out if there is a simple way to get all the users that have a role or another role.
On the official documentation of Spatie Laravel Permissions, I couldn't find this.

I'm trying like this but I get all the users.

```
User::role(['Individual', 'Organisation', 'Venue'])->get();
```

I'm also trying like this:

```
User::whereHas("roles", function($q) {
                $q->orWhere(function ($query) {
                    $query->where("name", "Individual")
                        ->where("name", "Venue")
                        ->where("name", "Organisation");
                });
            })->get();
```

In the Db roles table I have:

[image]

Comment: swap the `orWhere` to the inner query (3 times) rather than the outer one

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/master/src/Models/Role.php#L61

The Role model has a "users" method. Just use `Role::findByName()` and then `$role->users`

Comment: I apologize, I found out that the first query I was using works properly, just I was not ordering the data I was getting and I could not see at the end the user that I expect to see.

Answer (score 8):

you can try `whereIn()` to [roles()](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/78e8f95eaaf0fe0d395cea4a6f6b2cc675a7a9bb/src/Traits/HasRoles.php#L40)   ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

```php
User::with("roles")->whereHas("roles", function($q) {
    $q->whereIn("name", ["Individual","Venue",'Organisation']);
})->get();
```

try `id` for better search as it is primary key

```php
User::with("roles")->whereHas("roles", function($q) {
    $q->whereIn("id", [6,7,8]);
})->get();
```

> **NOTE** here `name` should match exact string of roles name which in your database

Comment: Thank you for answering. Also in this case I don't get the users that are just organization.

Comment: If I take your code and I remove "Individual","Venue" I get the users that are Organisation..
So the string is correct

Comment: same problem using the id

Comment: for just organisation use where() directly no need to use whereIn, `$q->where("id", 5);`

Comment: @DavideCasiraghi try `with("roles")` then you will able to see is it correct result or not

Answer (score 4):

Get all users who have roles assigned

```php
$users_with_roles = User::has('roles')->get();
```

Get all users who do **not** have roles assigned

```php
$users_without_any_roles = User::doesntHave('roles')->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

@Apokryfos meant you to change it like this

```
User::whereHas("roles", function($q) {
                $q->where("name", "Individual")
                    ->orWhere("name", "Venue")
                    ->orWhere("name", "Organisation");
            })->get();
```

if you instead want the users to have all roles and not one of the roles

```
User::whereHas("roles", function($q) {
        $q->where("name", "Individual")
    })->whereHas("roles", function($q) {
        $q->where("name", "Venue")
    })->whereHas("roles", function($q) {
        $q->where("name", "Organisation")
    })->get();
```

Comment: I tried like this but I don't' get the users that are just Organization

Comment: @DavideCasiraghi did the second one fail too ?

Comment: I need just the first one..  I need an OR, not and AND.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
$superadminRole = Role::where('name', 'superadmin')->first();
$superadminUsers = User::role($superadminRole)->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**